# Create rails form to modify database values - but not with a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a universal settings page for my rails app and I have no idea where to start. I know there are several gems that make it simple, and I've read the docs. They enable you to do something like Settings.color = "red" and your settings for color will be red! But, how do I turn this into a form, connected to the database, that the users can then change the values?

Ideally, we need a few settings, I know one of them will be a select box where they have numerous options but only one can be chosen at a time (think Active, Suspended, Disabled, etc).

This isn't really something that a model should be used for because its not a thing, right? I'm totally lost. I can make a database table, but without a model or a controller I have no idea how to just "make a form" that saves into the database - and then how do I get those values out?

Edit: The plug ins I'm referring to are similar to https://github.com/Squeegy/rails-settings and its variants. They show you how to hard code settings which is great, but don't go into how to create a form or any of the back end stuff to make it work. It's not a model so I'm totally clueless here. There's no scaffolding to work off of.

Comment: Don't these plugins have documentation.  If someone has built something extensive already then it would be best to investigate them.  Which plugins are you referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/Squeegy/rails-settings mainly. Great, it shows me how to hard code settings - how do I make a form to edit them and save them into the database? It's not model-based so I have no clue!

Answer (score 0):

`rails-settings` is model based, as the readme specifically states that.

So you'd just do as per any other model-based form.

Comment: Yes but its a plug in / gem - not one that I made. So do I just make a new view with.. whatever and it will work? I'm most confused about how to create the form and hook it in - does the form need to be its own model?

Comment: Looks like everything else is up to you.  You'd need to create the controller and add the routes yourself to whatever methods you wanted to.